# Any good scientific way to measure the ability of plastic to withstand compression force at home?

Tags: measurements, instrumentation

I want to test plastic's ability to withstand compression force scientifically. However, I don't have those compression machine. Are there other good ways to do it scientifically at home?

Comment: what does `scientifically` mean in this scenario?

Comment: compression over time or impact?

Comment: I would think "scientifically" in this case means consistent, repeatable, and quantitative. I would get an arbor press to to do the compressing, a scale to measure the force, and a plunger dial indicator to measure the displacement. Might be a very hefty scale though depending on what you are trying to compress. Even a small arbor press easily exceeds your typical bathroom scale. I wouldn't get a very expensive dial indicator either in case a mishap happens and depending how you set it up, it may or may not be subject to damage when the workpiece fails.

Comment: Yes, you are right. "scientifically" in this case means consistent, repeatable, and quantitative. 

Compression over time.

Comment: gonna depend on the plastic. some become brittle with age, which is a particularly troublesome failure mode, and it's in compression